# Combining OrderIDs together

Tags: mysql, sql

The orderID returns multiple results for the same ID due to different productIDs. What is the correct procedure to combine multiple results into a single row?

```
select distinct od.OrderID, p.ProductID, p.ProductName,
        p.QuantityPerUnit, p.UnitsInStock, p.UnitsOnOrder,
        sum(od.Quantity) as 'Quantity'
from Products p
join OrderDetails od on p.ProductID = od.ProductID
group by od.OrderID, od.Quantity, p.ProductID, p.ProductName,
        p.QuantityPerUnit, p.UnitsInStock, p.UnitsOnOrder
```

Hopefully I'm on the right track, thanks for the support.

Comment: Try removing `od.Quantity` from your `GROUP BY` clause.  Also, please add a tag to your question for the form of `SQL` that you are using, i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.

Comment: You, can improve the quality of your question by showing us the structure of your source tables along with some sample data, and how you would like the results to appear (based on the sample data).